# How to get started with creating custom camera intent for image capture?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I am using inbuilt camera api for capturing image from device but it only allows me to capture one image. Is there any way for me to create a intent where I can click multiple images ?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way for me to create a intent where I can click multiple images ?

No, sorry. You will need to use the camera directly, such as via CameraX, Fotoapparat, CameraKit/Android, or other wrapper libraries.